# Как правильно с помощью регулярного выражения, вывести нужное значение из текстового документа?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть текстовой документ, не совсем текстовой, csv. В котором хранятся следующие строки:

```
08/04/2021 16:57:42,Игрок Bolz убил игрока Iframe
08/04/2021 16:57:42,Игрок Bolz убил игрока Iframe
08/04/2021 16:57:42,Игрок ya_tvoia_slabost убил игрока Iframe
08/04/2021 16:57:42,Игрок maskim убил игрока Iframe
08/04/2021 16:57:42,Игрок kerill убил игрока Iframe
08/04/2021 16:57:42,Игрок vika убил игрока Iframe
08/04/2021 16:57:42,Игрок opaopa убил игрока Iframe
08/04/2021 16:57:42,Игрок petr убил игрока Iframe
08/04/2021 16:57:42,Игрок igor убил игрока Iframe
08/04/2021 16:57:42,Игрок Kesha убил игрока Iframe
```

Хочу сделать, чтобы после первого слова `Игрок` вывелось имя, а остальное не задевать. Чтобы получился вывод:

```
Bolz
Bolz
ya_tvoia_slabost
maskim .... и т. д
```

Comment: что именно у вас не получилось?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Брать первую группу:

```
Игрок (\S+)
```

Или с предпросмотром назад:

```
(?<=Игрок )\S+
```

Если имя игрока может содержать пробелы, то первая группа от:

```
^[^,]+,Игрок (.*) убил игрока
```